# Testing dispersion of values between condition on a group

Tags: standard-deviation, significance

I may have a tricky question. I have a within design where every participant is tested in 2 conditions. I want to compare the dispersion of the measure, for the two condition, with the hypotheses that one condition has a larger dispersion than the other one.
I though about taking the sd to get a measure of dispersion by condition and participant. After that I don't know if I have the right to test for a statistical difference by using a t test on the group (just a paired t test).
I'd be grateful if anyone can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the [F-test for equality of two variances.](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda359.htm)

You didn't specify a language (and if there's no programming, this question would be more appropriate for CrossValidated) but in R it looks like:

```
#make some dummy data
d <- data.frame(subj_id = c(1:1000,1:1000),
                cond = c(rep("Control",1000),rep("Exposed",1000)),
                resp = c(rnorm(1000,10,1),rnorm(1000,10,2)) # make different variances
                )
var.test(d$resp[d$cond=="Exposed"],
         d$resp[d$cond=="Control"])

# F test to compare two variances
# 
# data:  d$resp[d$cond == "Exposed"] and d$resp[d$cond == "Control"]
# F = 4.0976, num df = 999, denom df = 999, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   3.619378 4.638939
# sample estimates:
#   ratio of variances 
# 4.097569
```